# CakePHP: Alternative for Iframe?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, iframe

I am currently using an Iframe to display a source from another domain on my page.

I was wondering if there was a better solution with Cakephp?

Is it possible to display a site from another domain with php or ajax-jquery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: with ajax you can't do requets to another domain

Comment: maybe remove cakephp reference because the solution is just plain old php and has not really anything todo with cake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With php, you can try to use `file_get_contents`

http://php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php

With ajax that is difficult because you can't make a request in ajax to an other domain but if you is the owner, you can use  the special header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Answer (score 1):

In php you can use file_gets_contents().

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for jQuery ajax these links may help.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can also try this:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js